# Embedding links in flash buttons

Tags: html, flash, actionscript-3

I'm making a flash website, I know the basics of html and AS3, but this is my first time trying to use them together. I need only two interactions between the swf file and the server:

The .swf needs to be able to grab image files from a directory hosted on the server

The .swf file needs to be able to change the URL

I'm not sure how complex these things are to do, but I'd like the simplest solution possible. Direct me to a tutorial if you think it is necessary, but the quick and dirty would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Loading images](http://blog.728media.com/2009/03/11/how-to-load-external-images-in-actionscript-30/)

[Changing URL](http://snipplr.com/view/9312/as3-geturl--navigatetourl-how-to-make-clickable-links-in-as3/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to interact between flash and the browser you can use ExternalInterface.  Here is a simple tutorial on it:

[ExternalInterface](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/156/tn_15683.html)

Flash can access directory hosted on the same server as long as you have permission, and you can do redirect in AS3 w/ the following code:

```
var page3URL:String = "http://example.com?" + "x=" +id;
navigateToURL( new URLRequest( page3URL ) );
```